# Store coordinates of a clicked data point from the figure window

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure

In MATLAB, I can select a data point using the Data Cursor tool and it will display the X and Y of that point (*see figure below*).

[image]

Is it possible to wait for the user to click a point then store the X coordinate (or index) of this point to a variable within my code? It doesn't necessarily have to be using the Data Cursor tool, I just need a way to store the clicked point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this using the function `datacursormode` documented through MathWorks [here:](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datacursormode.html) I should have done some deeper digging.

Here is what I did:

```
dcmObject = datacursormode;
pause
datacursormode off
cursor = getCursorInfo(dcmObject);
x = cursor.Position(1)
```

The code turns on Data Cursor, waits for the user to select a point and then stores the position of the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the coordinates from a rendered image or plot via:

```
msgbox('Click on the plot')
[x y] = ginput(1)

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
x is the x coordinate of the click
y is the y coordinate of the click
```

**References**

---

1. *Graphical input from mouse or cursor*, Accessed 2014-07-08, [`<http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ginput.html>`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ginput.html)

Comment: This was the right idea, but I wanted the coordinates of only the data point, not any interpolated points in between.

Comment: Looks like you figured it out. Cheers!